# Power BI: How to change the background color for specific rows in a matrix?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I want to change the background color for specific rows in a matrix based on the name of the row.
[Here is my matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBec2.png)

What I did so far was to create a conditional column X in the data table that says, for example, when asset_name is A82 give me 1, in all other cases give me 0. Then for each field in *Values*, I created a [conditional rule based on that X column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfEOA.png) -
when column X is 1 - blue color, when is 0 - white color. Basically, I apply conditional background color for the columns. However, I want to be able to conditionally color the rows. There is no option to choose a background color for the fields in *Rows*. Therefore, I'm able to custom-color only the column part of the matrix.
Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use something like this - you can conditionally format a row based on the value of a measure https://www.cloudfronts.com/conditional-formatting-by-row-in-a-matrix/